# Edit decimal model properties in C# ASP .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, decimal-point

I have Simple model with one decimal property:

```
public class Model {
    public decimal Quantity { get;set; }
}
```

In my view I have:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quantity)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Quantity)
```

The thing is that when I try to post value with decimal part (like 1.5, 2.5 etc.) I get validation errors on client or server sides depending which `NumberDecimalSeparator` I use. If I post `1,5` I get client side validation error (the data-val-number one) or if I post `1.5` I get server side model validation error - `"The value '1.5' is not valid for Quantity."`. I tried to set `NumberDecimalSeparator` manually on `Application_Start()` in Global.asax but it didn't help.

```
var currentCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
currentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentCulture;
```

When I manually added some values to the database and tried to edit them, the value in TextBox is displayed with dot `"."`, but when I try to save another value with the dot I get server side validation error. What could be the reasons? Why didn't manual culture info update work?

**// EDITS:**
My approach with changing `currentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` works but only if I do it each time on `Application_BeginRequest()`:

```
protected override void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
       var currentCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
       currentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
       currentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
       currentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";

       Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
       Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentCulture;
       base.Application_BeginRequest(sender, e);
}
```

Why doesn't it work on application start?

Comment: What is the culture of the server? If it accepts the decimal separator as a comma, then you can modify the jquery.validator to accept the decimal separator as comma (by default its a dot)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, the culture of the server is `culture="ru" uiCulture="ru-RU"` also I want to use dot as decimal separator, as it is by default.

Comment: Does it work if you change the culture (to say `en-US`)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, yes, It does. Dot,in that case, is valid separator for client and server side validators.

Comment: Try putting your code for setting the culture in `Application_AcquireRequestState` rather than `Application_Start`

Answer (score 3):

I think it's logical that it's not working in `Application_Start` because you set culture per thread.

You can set culture globally in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But if you want (as in your example) to have Russian culture but with different decimal separator, then I think `Application_BeginRequest()` might be a good candidate. According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx):

> Occurs as the first event in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution when
>   ASP.NET responds to a request.

But you need to be careful, because this event is fired on literally **every** request.

I solved the similar problem not so long ago. In my case user had a possibility to switch between cultures. So every user culture was saved in database and because of that we used `Initialize` method of controller instead of `Application_BeginRequest()`. Then we set all the rules for client validation based on current thread culture.

I think such functionality can be also moved to filter like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560796/set-culture-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent blogpost about this issue. [I answered this already to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329942/asp-net-mvc-with-jquery-validation-and-html-editorfor-and-different-decimalsepar/22372326#22372326).

> The approach I used is to extend the jQuery validator. It is based on
> [this blogpost](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx). I setted the culture in the metadata to BE-nl. Since
> this is a pure Dutch website, I don't do any checks further on.
>
> ```
> $(function () {
>     // Look in metatag what culture we want
>     // and set this as culture for the client side.
>     var data = $("meta[name='accept-language']").attr("content");
>     Globalize.culture(data.toString());
>
>     // Don't validate on keyup event because it will mess up
>     // the cursor when replacing values in a textbox.
>     $('form').each(function () {
>     var validator = $(this).data('validator');
>     if (validator) {
>         validator.settings.onkeyup = false;
>     }
> });
>
> // Belgianize/sanitize the numbers inserted
> // 1 000 000    =>      1000000
> // 1.00         =>      1,00
> $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
>     var s = value.replace(/\ /g, '').split('.').join(',');
>
>     if (s.split(',').length < 3) {
>         var number = Globalize.parseFloat(s);
>         if (!isNaN(number)) {
>             $(element).val(s);
>             return this.optional(element) || true;
>         }
>     }
>
>     return this.optional(element) || false;
> }; });
> ```
>
> I think I used [this jQuery library](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) for the globalization